# Index Match with WildCards - Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I can't quite find the solution to this problem.

Here is how my document is setup:

Sheet 1 - Contains 1 column with multiple rows of data each containing a paragraph of text.

Sheet 2 - Contains a single column of multiple rows, each row containing a keyword (thousands of rows).

Formula tried:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(""&Sheet1!A:A&"",'UK - Internal'!G:G,0),0)
```

What I want to do is check to see if each description in sheet 1 contains any of the keywords from sheet 2. I believe this is possible using index match however I can't seem to figure it out. Please note there are multiple keywords (thousands) so it isn't possible to use just the match function.

Comment: ... and what would you do once one is found? What if more than one is found? Where is the sample data with expected results? What have you tried so far (working or not)?

Comment: Hi @Jeeped. I would just like to mark the column next to each description as any value to differentiate it as containing one of the keywords, e.g. it could contain "1" or "true". It doesn't matter if there is more than one keyword in the description; I just need to know if there is at least one. I have tried index match =INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH("*"&Sheet1!A:A&"*",'UK - Internal'!G:G,0),0) but it is matching everything even if it does not contain the keyword (in this example I have a colum B that contains "1" to indicate if the description contains any of the keywords)

Comment: Hi @Jeeped I followed the other answer exactly and it didn't work. It keeps saying Excel ran out of resources. this is me just testing this on two keywords and a single description.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks @Jeeped